# Saving Output Distance From Many Coordinates Using Python For Loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, numpy, save

I am looking solution on how to save the output, the result from Python for loop searching distance from many coordinates subject to one location. The script used as follows:

```
import gpxpy.geo
import numpy as np

# Reference Point
lat1 = 8.1
lon1 = 108.9

# Range Points for Distance Determination Subject to Reference Point
lat2 = [3.120,5.933,1.490]
lon2 = [113.025,116.048,110.353]

dist = []
for i in range(len(lat2)):
    dist = gpxpy.geo.haversine_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2[i], lon2[i])/1000
    print dist

data=np.zeros((np.size(lon2),3))
#
data[:,0]=lat2
data[:,1]=lon2
data[:,2]=dist

np.savetxt('distant.dat',data,fmt='%9.3f')
```

The current result that I get from the generated file is like this:

```
3.120   113.025   752.406
5.933   116.048   752.406
1.490   110.353   752.406
```

Actual result is supposed to iterate to have several values in column three like this:

```
3.120   113.025   717.551
5.933   116.048   824.794
1.490   110.353   752.406
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `for` loop, `dist` is not a list.  Replace the loop with:

```
dist = [
    gpxpy.geo.haversine_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2[i], lon2[i]) / 1000
    for i in range(len(lat2))]
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. I thought when we declare the list (dist=[ ]) before for statement is sufficient enough in the iteration. The weird thing was, the result in console was correct but different in output file.

Comment: You could have fixed your loop with `dist.append(...` to add the result onto the list.  But comprehension is better.

Comment: Thanks again. I will try to apply dist.append(..) in my previous script. Hope it works.